# iPhone Documents Folder Library/Caches Security issue

Tags: ios, file, file-manager

I am developed one iOS Application. For security reason I downloaded All Audio/Video files to Documents folder under **Library/Caches**.

For using iTunes the end user can't take this video backups. But some of the External softwares easily open the **Library/Caches** and download all files from this folders.

My question is How to secure This Library/Caches folder or How to Not visibly stored files to Documents Directory.

Comment: Beaware that the `Library/Caches` directory might be emptied by Apple if the system is getting low on disk space. Also the `Library/Caches` is per app and therefor external software can't just open your apps `Library/Caches`

Comment: Actually you can pretty easily. Even iExplorer allows almost anyone to access your bundle-files.
I think without a decent encryption, there is no way to properly secure your app.

Comment: @Akaino you are correct. I think we need to encrypt files to make them secure. Otherwise we can easily access them using third party software like iExplorer.

Comment: File a Security bug with Apple. It will get more attention.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that the purpose of the "Data Protection" app feature? Or that stuff doesn't really protect the app's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't Hide files inside folder. we have option to make Files to NSDATA and Make DRM(Some own algorithms)

**Example:**

1. Get Files to NSData and Add Some Bytes to NSData, so this file is encrypted. if some one open this file means they can't open it.

Ex:

Original file data : ABCDEF

Encrypted Data(Add Some Contents/Bytes) : A%GB*CDE)F

Note : No one can't open this file because we add some contents to original file so its not valid file.

1. For Programatically when opening file you will remove the bytes then you can read file properly.

   Ex:

   Encrypted Data(Add Some Contents/Bytes) : A%GB*CDE)F

   We need to remove Extra contents : %G*)

   Original file data : ABCDEF

**Very Important : Don't use Third party algorithms. You will make your own algorithm.**

Thanks,

Comment: This is [security by oscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) which is considered very bad practice. This has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CoreData in this app, you may create additional entity for file data, set "Transformable" type for data and encrypt/decrypt it there. http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2012/07/securing-your-core-data-with-transformable-attributes/ can help.
You can use similar approach if you don't use CD - encrypt on save, decrypt on load(but you should store keys somewhere secure, maybe send them to server). Also you may want to download only requested files, not all of them.

You'll need to profile this anyway to ensure that it won't make app unusable. Also any really motivated attacker would have those files anyway, even with https connection and encryption, but legitimate users may suffer from additional "protection".

**Edit:** You may want to write some sensible code in plain C, so it's harder for attakers to get into your code.

Comment: Please Read My Question clearly. Your answer is not related to my question.

Comment: If you want just to make those files inaccessible(to some extent) without application, you should encrypt them somehow, so that files are not useful and you've secured Library/Caches(again, to some extent). I'm not sure there is a way to entirely hide those files from other apps in any of those folders, so if you want this, you'll have to change something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSData writeToFile:options:error: with the option NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete which will write it encrypted mode. or some other AES encryption method to encrypt data.