# App-only accessible folder in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have an ipad app in which i show PDF documents in a UIWebView from my server.I want users to be able to download these documents so that they can read them offline. However i want them to read it only in the app.Basically my question is: Is it possible to have a folder that is only accessible from the app but not by users.

Comment: Since apps work in a sandboxed mode it will be only accessible by your app anyway and nothing else, so you don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: user will download the file to his ipad and even after he closes the app he will be able to access it at a later date but the file will be hidden from user if he tries to explore it on documents folder.

Comment: Have you tested this and it is happening? Or are you asking is it possible and if so how do I stop it. Because the way Apps work in iOS unless they are jailbroken devices nothing can read what is inside your application just like your application can't read data in other apps, that's why it is called sandboxed.

Comment: Uses can access the pdf with other tools on Mac, if you want to prevent that, you'd better encrypt the file.

Comment: I havent tried it yet.I am able to show pdf's in my app.Now i'm trying to add the offline reading functionality, but from what i see when you try to download and save a file to ipad you save it to documents folder.But im looking for a hidden folder that i can download pdfs and show in my app.

Comment: @tfeseas yeah so. What's the issue? Have a read of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html every app has it's own documents folder that is contained within the app itself so you can store to it and access when offline. I'm not sure I see your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save it in the app bundle.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate new];
NSString *docName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld.pdf", (long long)[date timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:docName];
```

EDIT: acording your comments question i think the solution would be something like this:

```
NSString *str = @"http://myserver.com/myfile.ext";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if (content) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder 
    NSString *dataPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"myfile.ext"];
    [content writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: This seems like the answer i've been looking for but where do you get the document? i got a url that i must download the requested file from but i don't know how to implement it.by the way I changed the docName to my document id that comes from the database.

Comment: @tfeseas i think its what youre looking for. If you want to get the filename from wherever you just have to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create password to PDF file and Open PDF programatically with password.
2. You can Make Own DRM for PDF files.

Refer Following Link:

[iPhone Documents Folder Library/Caches Security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954380/iphone-documents-folder-library-caches-security-issue)